# DBpedia and SPARQL query Find related resources to a specific one

Tags: java, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a question: 
if I have (PHP) as a DBpedia resource and I would like to find the most 3 related resources to it.. is there any conditions to perform that?
I mean... can it be as simple as the following:

```
SELECT ?pre1 ?obj WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/PHP> ?pre1 ?obj}
```

or do I have to determine more conditions at where clause,like property or category or anything.
hope that I asked it right
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by related resources?

Comment: any DBpedia entity that could be related to php

Comment: Do you mean 'similar' to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you have written will give you all the related entities. Regardless of them being String or URIs. I don't really know what you mean by 3 most related. There is no way to know "most" related concepts in DBpedia. There might be various metrics you can use to detect what is more important than another. For example, you can personally define a metric that counts the number of occurrences for a specific predicate and the one with the highest count is what you want. But this is an arbitrary metric. Regarding the task that you have, you can put more restrictions in the where clause.

Comment: how can I use the ontology type to do that kind of restrictions ? I mean ... PHP is An Entity of Type : work as mentioned is the first line on http://dbpedia.org/page/PHP

Comment: If you say `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/PHP>  a dbpedia-owl:Work` is doesn't make sense. You can say perhaps that the object that you are extracting is `a dbpedia-owl:Work`. Is this `SELECT ?pre1 ?obj WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/PHP> ?pre1 ?obj. ?obj a dbpedia-owl:Work.}` what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to built a simple semantic network between a set of DBpedia resources. these resources are extract from any web page that has been browsed and stored in Array List (that's how my code is working)